# how to create a background process at regular interval in eclipse

Tags: android

I need a simple application built in eclipse which will initiate a background process.

The process is required to establish the average ambient noise at a regular interval (adjustable) then pass that value to a method.

As a default, establish the average ambient noise over a 10 second period, then pass that value to a method.

The process needs to perform 100% of the time while the device is in on, irrelevant of whether the screen is in standby mode or the host application is in the background.

The activity interface (when showing) just needs to show the last value passed to the method, and a way of shutting down the application.

Comment: This is not a site for asking other people to write software for you. If you are trying to write the software yourself and have come across a particular coding problem, then describe it and people will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a service for that

[Maintaining a time-based incrementing float whilst the app is paused or closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023107/maintaining-a-time-based-incrementing-float-whilst-the-app-is-paused-or-closed/20023734#20023734)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the service for that purpose.

Few good tutorials for its understanding and code are as below:

1) http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

2) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

3)http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_an_Android_Started_Service_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example

4) http://www.androidsnippets.com/basic-service-example-in-android